# How to create missing candlesticks in OHLCV data with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe built from a list and I'm trying to identify candles that could be missing. When a missing candle is found I would like to insert a new row in the Pandas dataframe with OHLC values of the previous day (row) and with volume set to 0.

```
list = [[1528992000000,
      9.462e-05,
      0.00010814,
      9.202e-05,
      0.00010544,
      4600204.415809431],
     [1529164800000,
      0.00010309,
      0.00010529,
      0.0001016,
      0.00010162,
      1987989.1357407586],
     [1529251200000,
      0.00010165,
      0.00010173,
      9.402e-05,
      9.508e-05,
      1724979.853516945]]

df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.columns = ['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime( df.index, utc = True, unit = 'ms')

In [627]: df
Out[627]: 
                               open      high       low     close  \
timestamp                                                           
2018-06-14 16:00:00+00:00  0.000095  0.000108  0.000092  0.000105   
2018-06-16 16:00:00+00:00  0.000103  0.000105  0.000102  0.000102   
2018-06-17 16:00:00+00:00  0.000102  0.000102  0.000094  0.000095   

                                 volume  
timestamp                                
2018-06-14 16:00:00+00:00  4.600204e+06  
2018-06-16 16:00:00+00:00  1.987989e+06  
2018-06-17 16:00:00+00:00  1.724980e+06
```

In this example the candle `2018-06-15 16:00:00+00:00` is missing and I would like to recreate a dataframe like this. How can I achieve that ?

```
                               open      high       low     close  \
timestamp                                                           
2018-06-14 16:00:00+00:00  0.000095  0.000108  0.000092  0.000105   
2018-06-15 16:00:00+00:00  0.000095  0.000108  0.000092  0.000105   
2018-06-16 16:00:00+00:00  0.000103  0.000105  0.000102  0.000102   
2018-06-17 16:00:00+00:00  0.000102  0.000102  0.000094  0.000095   

                                 volume  
timestamp                                
2018-06-14 16:00:00+00:00  4.600204e+06  
2018-06-15 16:00:00+00:00             0
2018-06-16 16:00:00+00:00  1.987989e+06  
2018-06-17 16:00:00+00:00  1.724980e+06
```

So basically I'm able to identify missing indexes by comparing indexes with a sequence of datetime covering the period, then I select the previous row of every missing candle and I create a list `new` with the desired data.

My problem is that I can't figure out what is the best way to insert the list into the dataframe. How can I do that ?

```
# Create sequence
start = pd.to_datetime( list[0][0], utc = True, unit = 'ms')
end   = pd.to_datetime( list[-1][0], utc = True, unit = 'ms')
sequence = pd.date_range(start, end)

# Compare sequence
diff = sequence.difference(df.index)

if len(diff) != 0 :

        for i in diff :

            prev = i + datetime.timedelta( days = -1 )
            row = df.loc[pd.Timestamp(prev)] # select previous row
            new = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], 0] # create desired data

            # Doesn't return an error but failed to insert the new row
            df.loc[i] = new
            #df.loc[pd.Timestamp(i)] = new
```

Comment: `new` is well inserted and it was simply missing a sort of dataframe index with `df.sort_index()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the missing dates directly to the dataframe by using [asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df = df.asfreq('D')
```

To add values of the previous day, you can use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

If you need volumes to be left out for a specific reason:

```
df = df.asfreq('D')    
cols = ['open','high','low', 'close'] # list of columns to update
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Volume will be NaN for the previously missing dates. If you need a 0, you could also use [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df['volume'].fillna(0))
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but was looking for something like this and your answer was the bomb.. thanks!